# How to solve this problem in react 17: export 'createPortal' (imported as 'createPortal') was not found in 'react-dom' (module has no exports)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-portal

I have this problem when I try to `import { MapContainer } from "react-leaflet"`.

I have react 17.0.2 version and I already installed **leaflet** & **leaflet-react**

[this is a pic of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPExr.png)

Comment: This might be better asked on the package's [Github issues page](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues).